# Flash Videos shows everything with a blue-tint after installing NVIDIA driver (not the one available under Additional Software

Tags: flash

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [flash video appears blue ubuntu 12.04 and Ubuntu 11.10](https://askubuntu.com/questions/117127/flash-video-appears-blue-ubuntu-12-04-and-ubuntu-11-10)

Recently installed driver downloaded from NVIDIA website and facing problem where all the youtube videos or any other site's flash videos, are being played with a blue-tint. For eg, the faces are blue and the surrounding atmosphere as well. I'm on Ubuntu 11.10. Any help?

I've already tried editing gstreamer-properties under video from Autodetect to custom but it hasn't resolved the issue.